# discord.py rewrite: How do i make a slash command only able to be ran 1 time every five hours

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do i made a 5 hour cooldown for my slash command?

(Im NOT using pycord, im using discord.py)

My code:

```
@slashDev.command(name='requestfeature', description='Requests feature to the bot devs') async def requestfeature(interaction: discord.Interaction, msg : str):
    webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/donttryme
    webhook.send(f"`request: {msg} from {interaction.user}`")
    await interaction.response.send_message('**Thanks for requesting a feature**', ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: When the command succeeds, store the current timestamp for the user in a database (such as SQLite, which has [support built into the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)). Then when the command is invoked, then you can check whether the stored timestamp is more than 5 hours before the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a cooldown decorator, like this:

```
from discord import app_commands

@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 18000)
```

1 is the amount of uses the command has before the cooldown is triggered.
18000 being the cooldown in seconds.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown